# QSH claim mismatch for Zephyr API in Atlassian

Tags: jira, jira-zephyr

My api uri is this `/public/rest/api/1.0/executions/search/cycle/1fb7c831-61cd-4cc3-b070-fb0a46d5c8f7?versionId=10268&projectId=12853`

and the canonical path I inputted for qsh is `GET&/public/rest/api/1.0/executions/search/cycle/1fb7c831-61cd-4cc3-b070-fb0a46d5c8f7&versionId=10268&projectId=12853`

But I get a qsh claim mismatch. Can someone point me where I went wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Zephyr API is being called for each and every action. JWT token generated is directly related to the canonical path of URI i.e. the end point you are trying to access.

In other words, token generated for canonical path

```
  GET&/public/rest/api/1.0/executions/search/cycle/1fb7c831-61cd-4cc3-b070-fb0a46d5c8f7**&**versionId=10268&projectId=12853
```

It has &, where as the API you are trying to access is

```
/public/rest/api/1.0/executions/search/cycle/1fb7c831-61cd-4cc3-b070-fb0a46d5c8f7?versionId=10268&projectId=12853
```

has ?